# Definition: is a graph allowed to have a "dangling" edge without a vertex at its end(s)?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, definition

My textbook gives the following definition "a graph $G=(V,E)$ consisting of $V$, a nonempty set of vertices and $E$, a set of edges. Each edge has either **one or two** vertices associated with it."

Now consider this "graph", `o—`, where `o` is a vertex and `—` is an edge. Is this  a valid graph? If so, is it a subgraph of `o—o` ? (I know `—` is not valid because $V$ has to be nonempty)

(My textbook: "A subgraph of a graph $G=(V,E)$ is a graph $H=(W,V)$ where $W \subseteq V$ and $F \subseteq E$". My book also says "when edges and vertices are removed from a graph, **without removing endpoints of any remaining edges**, a smaller graph is obtained; such a graph is called a subgraph of the original graph")

What're the most "standard" definitions of graphs and subgraphs?

Comment: No, there must be a vertex at each end. The reason for the *one or two* in the definition is that the edge can be a *loop*, meaning that it has the same vertex at both ends.

Comment: ah, I see. I just discovered [half-edges and loose edges on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(mathematics)#Half-edges.2C_loose_edges), but the convention is for edges to be between **pairs** of vertices. Thanks!

Comment: You’re welcome!